# Choosing data from list and plot

Tags: plotting, filtering

I have a data set like below:

```
Angle={5.48575, -0.669213, 45.9832, 8.63878, -16.8777, 50.022, -41.8882,
    -45.956, 28.3005, 35.8234}
```

Now want to select the data for Angle > 20 and plot it. How can I do that?

Comment: `Angle // Pick[#, Clip[#, {20, 20}, {-1, 1}], 1] & // ListLinePlot` is another possibility.  (As 'built-ins' all start with a capital letter, it might be better to use `angle` rather than `Angle`?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this way?

```
ListLinePlot[Pick[Angle, UnitStep[20 - Angle], 0]]
```

Also possible and probably better to read:

```
Select[Angle, (# > 20 &)]
```

or

```
Select[Angle, Function[x, x > 20]]
```